# Unity's transform.RotateAround usage with lerp

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, lerp

I am working on a 3D Camera controller, where player is able to rotate the camera around an object using mouse. `transform.RotateAround()` is perfect for this, except for one thing - I can't figure out a way to smoothly lerp it.

For reference - this is old code, which made camera rotate smoothly, but without a specific Target, just around an arbitrary point:

```
private void Rotate(){
        if(!EnableRotation || RotationTarget == null) return;
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)) _newRotation = Quaternion.identity;

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1)){
            float xInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

           _newRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * RotationSpeed * xInput * RotationSensitivity);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateRotation(){
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation,_newRotation,Time.deltaTime * RotationDampening);
    }
```

And this, is what I have currently:

```
private void Rotate(){
        if(!EnableRotation || RotationTarget == null) return;
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)) _newRotation = Quaternion.identity;

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1)){
            float xInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

            transform.RotateAround(RotationTarget.position,Vector3.up,RotationSpeed * xInput);
        }
    }
```

So my big question is - is there a way to lerp the rotation of `transform.RotateAround()`? Make it smooth. Or are there any other ways of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

I feel like I've tried everything, but no success so far.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `Rotate()` called? Is the `rotationSpeed * xInput` meant to represent degrees as [required](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)?

I figure first the `UpdateRotation()` method was called frequently, while the `Rotate()` method was called to set the new rotation, in the new version you do the rotation on `Rotate()` are you calling it as often as you did with the `UpdateRotation()`?.

You could [Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) 360 degrees such as `Vector3.Lerp(0, 360, t)` where `t` should range from 0 to 1. Or simply adjust the rotation speed accordingly, making sure you call the method enough times to have a smooth rotation.